# Using dplyr to filter rows

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe

```
soDf <- structure(list(State = c("Exception", "Exception", "Exception",  "Exception", "Approval", "Processing"), User = c("1","2", "1", "3", "1", "4"), Voucher.Number = c(10304685L, 10304685L, 10304685L,10304685L, 10304685L, 10304685L),  Queue.Exit.Date = c("8/24/2016 14:59", "8/26/2016 13:25", "8/26/2016 15:56", "8/26/2016 16:13", "8/26/2016 16:25", "8/26/2016 17:34")),.Names = c("State", "User", "Voucher.Number","Queue.Exit.Date"), row.names = 114:119, class = "data.frame")
```

I have a list of rules that I want to filter rows by:

One of the rules being

```
(Voucher.Number == lag(Voucher.Number)) & (State == 'Exception' & lag(State) == 'Exception' )
```

If the current and lag voucher number are equal, and both have an exception tag, then count mark that row as `True`.

When I apply this rule with a couple other it returns the **4th** row as `True` when it should be returned as `False`

```
       State User Voucher.Number Queue.Exit.Date toFilt
1  Exception    1       10304685 8/24/2016 14:59     NA
2  Exception    2       10304685 8/26/2016 13:25   TRUE
3  Exception    1       10304685 8/26/2016 15:56   TRUE
4  Exception    3       10304685 8/26/2016 16:13   TRUE
5   Approval    1       10304685 8/26/2016 16:25  FALSE
6 Processing    4       10304685 8/26/2016 17:34  FALSE
```

Here is the code I used with all of the filtering rules

```
soDf <- soDf %>%
  arrange(Voucher.Number, Queue.Exit.Date)%>%
  mutate(toFilt =  ((User == lag(User)& Voucher.Number ==lag(Voucher.Number)))|
           ((Voucher.Number != lag(Voucher.Number)) & State == "Exception") |
           ((Voucher.Number == lag(Voucher.Number)) & (State == 'Exception' & lag(State) == 'Exception' ))|
           ((Voucher.Number == lag(Voucher.Number)) & (User == lag(User))))
```

Comment: you mean `soDf %>% filter((Voucher.Number == lag(Voucher.Number)) & (State == 'Exception' & lag(State) == 'Exception' ))` ...you need to call `filter` in order to...well..filter your data

Comment: @Sotos I didnt include later code but I use `filter` to filter rows == True. At theis point im interested in seeing the result...well because Im interested in it.

Comment: In your question code just replace `mutate(toFilt = ....)` with `filter(((User == ...)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 5 does not meet your conditional statement in the mutate column. The state of line 5 is "Approval" as opposed to "Exception", and the User ID does not match the lagged user ID.

For this reason, it returns FALSE as none of the 4 statements are TRUE. It does not appear to be a coding error just the conditional statement needs altering to match your needs. Hope this helps!

Comment: I meant to say the 4th row

Comment: The criterion is met on the conditional statement on the 4th row. It returns TRUE as the 3rd condition is TRUE: ((Voucher.Number == lag(Voucher.Number)) & (State == 'Exception' & lag(State) == 'Exception' ))